Issues with Gnome Classic on Ububntu 24.04
I am having issues with running Ubuntu Gnome Classic desktop on Ubuntu 24.04.
I having a Dell Latitute 7350 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and Gnome Classic as the front end.
Everything works fine until, I connect to it to an external monitor. I mainly face two issues:

Whenever I start the machine with my laptop connected to an external monitor, I normally get this error: Oh no! Something has gone wrong. "A problem has occured and the system can't recover. "

I have attached the screenshot: LogoutMesg1.jpg 1. Sometimes I get the error with a slightly different emoticon. This screenshot is also attached: LogoutMesg2.jpg 2
I took the screenshot from my cell phone.
This error occurs when I try to login. When I get this error, I will have to logout and login. This happens randomly multiple times. I keep trying to login and Then by chance I will finally be able to login.

The above error occurs only when my laptop is connected to an external monitor during login. When I am connected to the laptop without the external monitor, I am able to login without any issue. After logging in, when I connect an external monitor, most of time it is able to connect well to external monitor. But the sizing (aspect ratio) of the various windows is not correct.

I will illustrate this with the screenshot of VLC player in full size: VLC-Maximized.png 3. The various buttons on the VLC are below the bottom panel. This does not happen on my laptop.
If I minimize the VLC player, it works correctly. The minimized screenshot is attached for your reference: VLC-Minimized.png 4.
Any suggestions for both these issues? Do you want me to share any error logs?
Thanks
Sathya





For your second problem open bug here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel.
